# how can i do json format get a value?

Tags: c#

hello this my json value

How can I get a value ?

```
   "a195cc41-4b37-4192-8949-86ae109cfa80,{\"UserID\":2,\"CurrentSessionID\":\"746076a0-6ab9-415a-849a-2755837981bb\",\"Name\":\"SERDAR\",\"Surname\":\"SENGUL\",\"Email\":null,\"Password\":null,\"RememberMe\":false,\"IsActive\":false,\"IsDeleted\":false,\"CreateDate\":\"2015-01-17T09:15:03.6339968+02:00\"},17.01.2015 09:15:03"

var id =  clientAuth.Split(',')[0] > it's working (773484c2-5730-4cfa-a17e-2eb041e8c225)
var date =  clientAuth.Split(',')[11] > it's working (24.01.2015)
but I can not take get usermodel a value
that comes
var UserID =  clientAuth.Split(',')[1]  {\"UserID\":2"
var name =  clientAuth.Split(',')[2]  {\"Surname\":SENGUL"
var createDate =  clientAuth.Split(',')[2]  "\"CreateDate\":\"2015-01-17T08:44:30.1681286+02:00\"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your questions, you will need to do this:

```
var firstComma = rawData.indexOf(',');
var lastComma = rawData.lastIndexOf(',');
var jsonString = rawData.slice(firstComma+1,lastComma-firstComma);
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

and then you can refer to the properties of the object like:

```
var createdate = obj.CreateDate;
var surname = obj.Surname;
```

Good Luck.

EDIT: You can also use regular expressions to find the '{..}' string, if you prefer.

Comment: hi thank you your answer..yes, that's right but I see this error I think maybe "}"  http://i.hizliresim.com/04RZ8L.png

Comment: Of course, my bad.  You can't use split(',') because of the commas in the object.  Let me edit the answer.

Comment: You could use a regular expression like /\{[\s\S]+\}/ to match the object string.  That should work even if you have embedded objects, since Regular Expressions are greedy by default.

Comment: hi Beartums again thank you.. but I see this error :) Slice key not working I made a mistake? http://i.hizliresim.com/PY1VOQ.png

Comment: Sorry again.  I was in too much of a hurry.  `lastComma-firstComma` is 1 too big.  Should be `lastComma-firstComma - 1`.  I guess that will teach me to proofread.

Answer (score 0):

1.It's not a valid json.
2.Use [Json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/json) for parsing json's in you C# code:

```
  YourObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourObject>(json);
```

Comment: hello amir no it's currently valid json format
http://i.hizliresim.com/6la1aP.png

Comment: ok I fix the problem
and now it's works great
 but How can I get the value?
http://i.hizliresim.com/dWvJdn.png

Comment: you can build a C# object that will reflect your json(same properties) and then use the generic version on DeserializeObject like I did in my example or you can use a dynamic object(read about it) if you want to access you object dynamically.